# HTTP Request works with Postman but not in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, postman

I'm trying to make a HTTP Request to get data from a website.
To do that, I have to use a custom header. 
When I make a request with Postman, by adding well the custom header, everything works fine. When I remove the custom header, I get this error message : `{"error": "content not found"}`, which is normal.

I tried to make the same request in Rails.
This is my code :

```
uri = URI.parse("https://www.itqi.com/api/master-descriptor")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.path)
req["itqi-key"] = '************************'
response = http.request(req)
```

In this case, I added the custom header. But in despite this, I got no data, only this error message : `{"error": "content not found"}`, like if my custom header was not taken into account. I tried many possibilities without success.

Is there somebody who can help me ? I'm running out of ideas.

Thanks in advance for your advices.

Best regards,

**EDIT**

Here is my https request with Faraday :

```
conn = Faraday.new(:url => 'https://www.itqi.com', :ssl => {:verify => false})
response = conn.get do |req|
    req.url '/api/master-descriptor'
    req.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    req.headers['itqi-key'] = '********************'
end
```

And here is the server response :

> RESPONSE: #https://www.itqi.com/api/master-descriptor> @request=# @request_headers={"User-Agent"=>"Faraday v0.12.2", "Content-Type"=>"application/json", "itqi-key"=>"**********************"} @ssl=# @response=# @response_headers={"date"=>"Wed, 13 Dec 2017 08:25:53 GMT", "server"=>"Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)", "content-length"=>"29", "connection"=>"close", "content-type"=>"application/json; charset=UTF-8"} @status=404 @reason_phrase="Not Found">>

Always the same problem :(

************************ SOLUTION **************************

After some research, it seems to be that header keys are case sensitive in Rails. So, to resolve the problem, I had to force Rails to put them in lowercase. Without that, Rails systematically capitalized them.

There is my solution :

```
conn = Faraday.new(url: 'https://www.itqi.com', ssl: {verify: false}) do |conn|
  conn.request :json
  conn.response :json, :content_type => /\bjson$/
  conn.adapter Faraday.default_adapter
end
response = conn.get do |req|
  req.url '/api/master-descriptor'
  itqi_key = CaseSensitiveString.new('itqi-key')
  req.headers[itqi_key] = '************************'
end

class CaseSensitiveString < String
  def downcase
     self
  end
  def capitalize
     self
  end

  def to_s
    self
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not look like the example on http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#label-Setting+Headers.

But I suggest you'll be happier if you switch to Faraday (https://github.com/lostisland/faraday).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I used Faraday. But I have the same problem. I have again this error message : {"error": "content not found"}. How can I add this header : {"itqi-key" => '************************'}

Comment: What's your code look like now? It should do something like the following (case-senstive):

    `conn.get do |req|
        req.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    end`

Comment: I edited my post to include my code with Faraday and the server response. Have you got an idea why my headers are not taken into account ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're setting the header. Is the URL correct? I'd expect a 401 or a 403, not a 404.

Comment: Finally, the problem was resolved. After a lot of research, it seems that's Rails has sent the header with uppcases instead of with lowercases, which explains why the server didn't accept my resquet because the key could only be in lowercases. So I forced Rails to send my header in lowercases. After that, everything worked well. However, thanks for your help. Thanks to you, I discovered a new Gem ;-)

Comment: Post your solution here for posterity? I'm curious how Rails interferes with Faraday.

Answer (score 0):

The answer on this question i found in the same post client, where i can found examples of working query. Postman give me working code for javascript fetch:

```js
  const options: RequestOptions = {
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
    },
    method: method as string,
    mode: 'no-cors',
  }
  if ([RestMethods.post, RestMethods.put].includes(method as RestMethods)) {
    // isn't working:
    // options.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    // options.body = JSON.stringify(paramsSnakeCased)
    const urlencoded = new URLSearchParams();
    Object.keys(paramsSnakeCased).forEach((key: string) => {
      urlencoded.append(key, paramsSnakeCased[key])
    })
    options.body = urlencoded
    options.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  }

  fetch(url, options).then(resolve)
```